# What's the Netflix / vmaf result stand for?

Tags: ffmpeg

I ran the vamf between two mp4 files, and I got the result as:

```
<pooled_metrics>
<metric name="integer_adm2" min="0.294617" max="0.999526" mean="0.902007" harmonic_mean="0.899792" />
<metric name="integer_adm_scale0" min="0.559920" max="0.994265" mean="0.918411" harmonic_mean="0.917920" />
<metric name="integer_adm_scale1" min="0.372149" max="0.999764" mean="0.907398" harmonic_mean="0.905652" />
<metric name="integer_adm_scale2" min="0.226668" max="0.999331" mean="0.915917" harmonic_mean="0.912921" />
<metric name="integer_adm_scale3" min="0.224996" max="1.010998" mean="0.881612" harmonic_mean="0.878538" />
<metric name="integer_motion2" min="0.000000" max="32.177296" mean="6.365028" harmonic_mean="3.653298" />
<metric name="integer_motion" min="0.000000" max="145.765976" mean="7.202581" harmonic_mean="4.101624" />
<metric name="integer_vif_scale0" min="0.008498" max="0.910434" mean="0.247533" harmonic_mean="0.235043" />
<metric name="integer_vif_scale1" min="0.023310" max="0.990787" mean="0.457384" harmonic_mean="0.436370" />
<metric name="integer_vif_scale2" min="0.029596" max="0.995830" mean="0.529965" harmonic_mean="0.508850" />
<metric name="integer_vif_scale3" min="0.032303" max="0.997724" mean="0.586864" harmonic_mean="0.567116" />
<metric name="vmaf" min="0.000000" max="100.000000" mean="71.630354" harmonic_mean="61.321347" />
 </pooled_metrics>
```

I got the "vif" from the paper "IMAGE INFORMATION AND VISUAL QUALITY". However,what's the meaning of 4 scales of vif?
And any detail introduction about this result? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have knew that the 4 scales is based on Gaussian Pyramid。

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.